# How can I log without polluting method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, logging

I know about AOP and Postsharp but here the constraint is I can't use postsharp and using attributes for logging is having performance overhead.

But again right now I have to put log code in everymethod, a lot of copy paste and also it is not part of method. So, my functions are doing more than one work. It is somewhat not looks good to have business logic and log together.

Is there anyway out, like to make class open ended and can add log from out side of the class or function. Or I just have to go with traditional way of logging.

Please, let me know if any further information needed. Any suggestion of good/ another way of logging is also welcomed.

Comment: Enterprise Library and Unity.  you can use composition to create logging decorators around other classes that log then pass-through to the other class.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx

Comment: I think this will solve the problem. I will give it a try. Can you please give it as answer so, if problem solved I can close the answer by selecting correct answer.

Comment: Have you looked at using Castle DynamicProxy for method interception?

Comment: @levelnis I havent looked in to that, but I know about Catsle Dynamic Proxy. But I found unity more preferable approach as we already using it. But still I ll give it a try to castle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Library and Unity. You can use composition to create logging decorators around other classes that log then pass-through to the other class.

Check out [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hi as Peter Ritchie told, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx is good solution. You can aslo take a look at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17866 or to other DI framework like Ninject this is good one for MVC projects.
Any way this is good articale about DI perfomance http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can create decorators for your classes, take a look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern